# Count rows with value Yes in column Winforms

Tags: winforms, ms-access

I have a Winform with 3 column access table.  I find total number of rows in access table as below

```
lblnoofrow.Text = "Total no of rows :- " + tbl.Rows.Count.ToString()
```

Now I have to find number of rows with Yes in column named Completed.  Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already retrieved that table and you have it at your disposal in your code, you could count the rows with the YES string inside a column with this code

```
lblnoofrow.Text = "Total no of rows :- " + 
       tbl.AsEnumerable().Count(x => x.Field<string>("Completed") == "Yes");
```

Here I assume that your column is of type string, but if it is a YesNo field then change the `<string>` to `<bool>` and compare against true/false

```
lblnoofrow.Text = "Total no of rows :- " + 
       tbl.AsEnumerable().Count(x => x.Field<bool>("Completed") == true);
```

(well the compare against true is not really needed but in this case I think it makes things more readable)